# Windows CE 6 Device will not connect to PC

Tags: windows-ce, activesync

So, ive got a EPC 7" Netbook things (Smartbook) and it just does not want to connect.

Ive got Active Sync 4.5 running on a Win XP SP3 PC, and it just says the connection is unavaliable. Ive tried 2 USB Cables, and still nothing.

Do i need to run something on my device to start the connection going?

Device:
Windows Embedded CE v6.0

PC:
Windows XP Home Service Pack 3

Connection:
USB Cable

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this specific device.  Do you have a users manual that states ActiveSync is supposed to work with it?  Understand, Windows CE is a componentized OS and there's nothing that says that an OEM has to include any specific part of the OS catalog.  It's quite possible that ActiveSync isn't part of the OS.

If it does exist in the OS, there will be a file named `repllog.exe` in the \Windows folder.  You might try manually running it when you've connected